# When is executed the code defined in the class section of the model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

If I put this in my model:

```
class Sample < ApplicationRecord
  enum level: [:one, :two, :three].map{|e| [e,e]}.to_h
```

This section

```
[:one, :two, :three].map{|e| [e,e]}.to_h
```

Will be executed only once? when the model is first loaded? or it will be executed multiple times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once, when the model is loaded. In Ruby, a class definition is just code, so `enum` in your example is a method call, and `[:one, :two, :three].map{|e| [e,e]}.to_h` is an argument.

The end result of calling `enum` is that several other methods will be defined on the class, allowing you to do things like `sample.two?` as per the [docs](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html).

Have a read of the [source code on Github](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/a9dc45459abcd9437085f4dd0aa3c9d0e64e062f/activerecord/lib/active_record/enum.rb#L148) if you want to know how this happens.